# Python Pandas stack by zip code and group by month/year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, time-series, zipcode

I have a large data frame with transaction data. What I am trying to do is use python to aggregate the data starting with zip codes, then a year and month, finally the total number of transactions for that month.

My Df:

```
  Date        VAR1   VAR2    ZipCode    Transactions
YYYY-MM-DD.    X.     Y.     12345.         1.
```

So the first thing I did was convert the to date time

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
 df.info()
 # Date datetime64[ns]
```

Then I split the data into year-month and number of transactions:

```
# grouping the data by year and month
per = df.Date.dt.to_period("M")  
g = df.groupby(per)
g.sum() # so now that this works, we need to break it up into zip codes
```

Which gives an output of:

```
Date.       Transactions
YYYY-MM.        X
YYYY-MM.        Y
```

My questions is, what am I missing to get the zipcodes in front:

```
ZipCode.     Date.    Transactions
 123345.   YYYY-MM.     sum()
```

Any and all help is greatly apprecaited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need add column `ZipCode` to `groupby` if need grouping per zip and per months:

```
per = df.Date.dt.to_period("M")
df1 = df.groupby(['ZipCode',per])['Transactions'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm!